# How to read from a map in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map of `std::map<int,float,float> m_mapWheelvalue;` of 100 elements
I need to read the values .Code i am using is below:

```
float fvalue1,fvalue2;
std::map<double,float,float>::iterator itNewMap;
itNewMap= m_mapWheelvalue.find(20);     
if(itNewMap!= m_mapWheelvalue.end())
{           
        fValue1 = itNewMap->second;
        fValue2= itNewMap->third;  
}
```

but its giving error !!{ third not defined }
How to read third value
Please give proper solution

Comment: `but its giving error ` Post the error.

Comment: have you even tried figuring out how to use a map?

Comment: a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) with three parameters? third parameter of the template should be the comparison function.

Comment: (Objective-C is different from C++)

Comment: If the compiler responds: "No member third in ...", what do you think it can mean? If the compiler gives the message: "illegal type for parameter 3 in template...", what do you think it could mean? There is a simple trick: Read the description for stl members to figure out what they do and how they work.

Answer (score 3):

The following compiled for me:

```
#include <map>
int main(){
   std::map<double,std::pair<float,float> > m_mapWheelvalue;
   float fValue1,fValue2;
   std::map<double,std::pair<float,float> >::iterator itNewMap;
   itNewMap= m_mapWheelvalue.find(20);

   if(itNewMap!= m_mapWheelvalue.end()){
        fValue1 = itNewMap->second.first;
        fValue2= itNewMap->second.second;
   }
}
```

Notes:

- Look at [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) definition: first parameter is the key, second parameter is the entry... third parameter is the comparison function. I guess you wanted to have several values in the entry. I've chosen to use a pair (as you have two), if you have more you might want to define a struct/class.
- Check variable names, there are several case changes.
- The iterator to a map gets you a pair of key,entry... so itNewMap->first is the key, itNewMap->second is the entry.