# How to retrieve value from a map in c++

Tags: c++, maps

I have a map with some values. Then I have a function that returns some string, and this string will be a member of the keys in map. I need to retrieve the value based on the key and pass it to another function, which takes it as argument.

```
map<string,int> SymbolTable;
SymbolTable["R0"]=0;
SymbolTable["R1"]=1;
SymbolTable["R2"]=2;
SymbolTable["R3"]=3;

string value=getValue(); //this one will return something from R0 to R3
nextFunction(SymbolTable[value]);  // this part is wrong
```

If I give value=="R0" or some static value, this is working as expected. But whenever I pass this dynamic value, it returns 0 always, so my nextFunction is taking 0 as argument.
I tried to output the return value from getValue() to check what it is returning, and it is correct. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960963/how-to-read-from-a-map-in-c) and similar ways, but all gives me the same issue. Can someone guide me on what am I doing wrong here? TIY

Answer (score 1):

> If I give value=="R0" or some static value, this is working as
>   expected. But whenever I pass this dynamic value, it returns 0 always

It simply means the "dynamic value" you obtained does not exist as a key in the map. [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)'s [`operator []`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) inserts a default constructed value if the associated key does not exist.

To check for the existence of `value` in your map, you can do:

```
string value=getValue();
if(SymbolTable.count(value)){
    //key exists....
    nextFunction(SymbolTable[value]);  // this part should be correct now
}
```

or you can equally use [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)

Comment: Would be probably worth mentioning how to use `std::map<T>::find()`, to fix this issue.

Comment: I tried to output the return value from getValue() and it is what I am expecting

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Thanks. Done. Though, I have a bias for `count()` :-)

Comment: @WhiZTiM `count()` is actually good. It was me not being aware of it, sorry :-) ...

Comment: @EbinPIssac Demonstration of it working with Dynamic Values: http://ideone.com/8dvY3t. You should post your full, actual code.

Comment: What is the return type of getValue ()?

Comment: Return type is string